# Using JSON_TABLE to convert an ARRAY into Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have a database column (named "details") formatted as a JSON object that contains the following data:

```
'{"300-000012": {"is_complete": "False", "is_in_progress": "True"}, 
  "300-000018": {"is_complete": "True", "is_in_progress": "False"}}'
```

I can't seem to convert the Array into Columns.  I've tried

```
SELECT mh.*, jt.*
FROM history AS mh,
JSON_TABLE (mh.details, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS (
        NESTED PATH '$.*' COLUMNS (jt_complete VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.is_complete'),
        NESTED PATH '$.*' COLUMNS (jt_progress VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.is_in_progress')
        )
        ) AS jt)
```

But I get an Error Code

```
Error Code: 3143. Invalid JSON path expression
```

Ideally I would get something like:

```
  details             jt_complete            jt_progress
  300-000012             FALSE                  TRUE
  300-000018              TRUE                  FALSE
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thx

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing the data in JSON if you want them in individual columns?

Comment: We store all the information in a JSON object so it is in 1 row but then we need to break out the JSON object when we want to utilize the data.  LMK if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one because the keys of the object are variable. This means you need to extract the keys and the values separately for each object. The values can be connected by using an ordinality column for each `JSON_TABLE` and joining them on that:

```
SELECT mh.id, jk.details, jt.jt_complete, jt.jt_progress
FROM history mh
JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_KEYS(mh.details),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS (
    rn FOR ORDINALITY,
    details VARCHAR(10) PATH '$'
  )
) jk
JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_EXTRACT(mh.details, '$.*'),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS (
    rn FOR ORDINALITY,
    jt_complete VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.is_complete',
    jt_progress VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.is_in_progress'
  )
) jt ON jt.rn = jk.rn
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f2e6b3313c613b51429c3fe4bb3a4ee)

Comment: As a follow-on to this question - is it possible to return the Value JSON object as a single object (ie not broken apart)?  ie  details: 300-000012 and value: {"is_complete": "False", "is_in_progress": "True"} ?

Comment: @PrashantMarathay sure, you can put it together using `JSON_OBJECT`. See for example https://dbfiddle.uk/gILW18NN